# jQuery sorting lib that supports multilanguage sorting?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a sorting jQuery library that supports multilanguage sorting

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort elements that contain unicode data, you can use the jQuery sort using the javascript localCompare method as follows:

```
        function sort() {
          var li_options = $("#_myselect option");
          li_options.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.text.localeCompare(b.text);
          })
          $("#_myselect").empty().append(li_options);
        };
```